# Octave: Get Date Time Picker

Tags: octave

I am trying to tranlate Matlab code in Octave. I am looking for Date Timer picker. I am affraid that there is no such utility in Octave. If so, is there any alternate for this Matlab command in Octave.

uicalendar();

Using Octave: error: 'uigetdate' undefined

Do I need some package etc. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `uigetdate` does not exist in Octave core. It also does not exist in Matlab so I don't know where you got it from.

However, there is a function to pick a date from a calendar in the Octave [zenity package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/zenity/index.html). The zenity package is unmaintained but seems to still works fine.

```
octave> pkg load zenity
octave> date = zenity_calendar ()
date = 13-Nov-2017
```

Which will look like this on my system (Gnome 3):

[image: Zenity calendar display]

The Octave zenity package is a wrapper to the [zenity](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Zenity) program so you will need to have it installed in your system.

Comment: I have installed and loded zenity.  zenity *|   0.5.7 | C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.1\share\octave\packages\zenity-0.5.7--running command  "zenity_calender()"
error: 'zenity_calender' undefined near line 1 column 1

Comment: @Shahgee you have a typo on the function name.  It is `zenity_calendar`, and not `zenity_calender`

Comment: @ carandraug                                        pkg load zenity
>>  date = zenity_calendar ()
The "zenity" command is either misspelled or
could not be found. (translated with Google)
date =

Comment: @Shahgee sounds like you do not have the zenity program installed on your system. That's a different question and I have no clue on how to do it on Windows.